# Why is print portion of this program that takes info of 11 cars and prints the model name of red cars not working?

Tags: c

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int val;
    struct info{
        char model[50];
        int price;
        char color[30];
    }car[11];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter model name:\n");
        scanf("%s",&car[i].model);
        printf("Enter price:\n");
        scanf("%d",&car[i].price);
        printf("Enter color:\n");
        scanf("%s",&car[i].color);
    }
    printf("\nThe red cars are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        val=strcmp("red",tolower(car[i].color));
        if(0==val)
        {
            printf("%d. %s\n",i+1,car[i].model);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

also I tried using gets for string input but it doesn't seem to work.

Here are the warnings:

```
*main.c:17:17: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%s",&car[i].model);

main.c:21:17: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%s",&car[i].color);

main.c:26:34: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘tolower’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         val=strcmp("red",tolower(car[i].color));

In file included from main.c:4:0:
/usr/include/ctype.h:124:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 extern int tolower (int __c) __THROW;

main.c:26:26: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         val=strcmp("red",tolower(car[i].color));

In file included from main.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
```

Comment: "not working" is not a good problem description. Instead of filling up the post with junk text how about actually describe the input, expected result and actual result or errors?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please add it. [tolower()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower)

Comment: `tolower` converts a *single character* to lower case, not an entire string.

Comment: Did you look at the compiler warnings? `tolower` requires an `int` not a `char *`.

Comment: What errors/warnings did your compiler give you when you compiled this code?  If it gave you warnings you need to understand and fix them.  If it gave you no warnings you need to get a better compiler.  You cannot learn modern C if your compiler quietly lets you make glaring errors as you have made in this code.

Answer (score 2):

You posted your compiler output.  Good.  Let's look at all those errors:

> `main.c:17:17: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’`

Most of the time, when you call `scanf`, you need `&` on the variable being stored, but `%s` is an exception.  (Explanation elsewhere.)  Get rid of the `&`: `scanf("%s",car[i].model);`

> `main.c:26:34: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘tolower’ makes integer from pointer without a cast`

This is your main problem.  Your program as written will never work.  `tolower` expects a single character to convert, but you're passing it a pointer instead.  (You're passing it a pointer to the entire string you want to convert.)

> `/usr/include/ctype.h:124:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’`

This is another message explaining the `tolower` problem.

> `main.c:26:26: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`

`tolower` returns the single character it has converted.  But `strcmp` expects an entire string.

> /usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

This is another message explaining the `tolower`/`strcmp` problem.

---

How to fix this?  There is not a standard function (that I can remember) that converts an entire string to lowercase.  You'd have to write that yourself.  Another option is to use a version of `strcmp` that compares the strings without regard to case.  Two such functions (neither of which is quite standard, however) are `strcasecmp` and `stricmp`.

Answer (score 0):

tolower only works with char not string, so use the function on every char of the string.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int strcicmp(char const *a, char const *b)
{
    if (!a && !b)
        return 0
    else if (!a || !b)
        return -1
    for (;; a++, b++) {
        int d = tolower((unsigned char)*a) - tolower((unsigned char)*b);
        if (d != 0 || !*a)
            return d;
    }
}

    int main()
    {
        int val;
        struct info{
            char model[50];
            int price;
            char color[30];
        }car[11];

        int i;

        for(i=0;i<11;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter model name:\n");
            scanf("%s",&car[i].model);
            printf("Enter price:\n");
            scanf("%d",&car[i].price);
            printf("Enter color:\n");
            scanf("%s",&car[i].color);
        }
        printf("\nThe red cars are:\n");
        for(i=0;i<11;i++)
        {
            val=strcicmp(car[i].color, "red");
            if(0==val)
            {
                printf("%d. %s\n",i+1,car[i].model);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I've taken your commentaries into account, this should be better!

Comment: What does your `strcicmp` return if it passes the for loop?

Comment: I thought it was never supposed to do so, the only way to exit the loop is if the check is validated, isn't it  ?

Though I have not included the NULL checks